# How to handle updating JDO class definitions on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I'm using the Google app engine and JDO.  What is the best way to update a JDO class definition without having to wipe the data store contents first?

I'm not sure if this is specific to JDO on GAE, but I noticed that when I simply change the name of one of my persistent fields from `svotes` to `votes`, an exception is thrown (`java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: svotes`).

I expect once my site goes live I might want to make some changes to my JDO class definitions, such as adding a field or something. Any suggestions for how to update the data definitions without having to wipe the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Google has a python related article about updating the schema: http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/update_schema.html. The guidelines can be applied to java too.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried some of the methods mentioned [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/creatinggettinganddeletingdata.html)?